# Is "またまた" actually used by anyone in Japan to mean "bye" or "see you later"?

Tags: usage, slang, greetings

For years I have been saying "またまた" for "see you" to Japanese people I meet. Well at least half the time, since I also often say "またね".

But only tonight for the first time did anybody pick me up on it and tell me it's not right! I arrived yesterday in Okinawa for the first time.

So I know a more "proper" way to say it is "じゃあまた" and considered "またね" as a bit more informal. I had always thought I picked up "またまた" from a backpacker I met either at home in Australia or in a hostel in some third country. Possibly even from staff in a hostel in Japan.

So is it something I just imagined or made up myself? Or is it actually used as slang by young people in some part of Japan?

Answer (score 5):

またまた is a word, but as far as I know never used in the sense of "see you later", which, as you know, would be (じゃあ)またね.

(またまた means something like "yet again", e.g. またまた驚かされた "you surprised me yet again".)

Comment: またまた on its own would probably be interpreted as "Oh you!", as in what you say when someone is kidding about something (yet again).